# Property sheet handler doesn't work with Windows 10/Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, shell-extensions

I have a shell extension that has been working for quite a while. It does:

- icon overlays
- adds a context menu
- adds property page

When compiled using VS 2013 it all works fine on all supported windows versions (7 though and including 10).

I've recently migrated to VS 2015. Now it still works fine for Win 7, 8, 8.1. When installed in Windows 10, the icon overlay and context menu work, but the property page doesn't load. When debugging, the AddPage call never gets called.

Thanks for any ideas.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue described here except that it happened compiling with VS 2013 and running on Windows 10. In our extension we do some stuff in DllMain() including the creation of a Poco::Logger. What I found by trial and error was that removing this from DllMain enabled the property sheet to display ! Still don't know the reason for this but suspect it may be a COM threading model issue which is somehow only in play under Windows 10.